# DelayedConfirmationView is blank on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm attempting to use Andoird Wear's DelayedConfirmationView from the support library, by starting an activity.

The activity has this in OnCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.delayed_main);
mDelayed = (DelayedConfirmationView) findViewById(R.id.delay);
mDelayed.setTotalTimeMs(4000);
//mDelayed.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close_button));
mDelayed.setListener(new DelayedConfirmationView.DelayedConfirmationListener() {
...
```

My delayed_main has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/android.support.wearable.view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DelayedConfirmActivity">

<android.support.wearable.view.DelayedConfirmationView
    android:id="@+id/delay"
    app:circle_border_color="#2299ee"
    app:circle_border_width="5sp"
    app:circle_color="#222222"
    app:circle_padding="5sp"
    app:circle_radius="80sp"
    app:update_interval="100"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get no exception in my OnCreate, but all I get is a blank white screen. I've tried setImageDrawable. Also tried setContentView(View) passing in a new DelayedConfirmationView instance.  Also tried deleting all the app: attributes in the above XML (hoping that some sensible defaults will apply). The docs don't give any example as to what to expect, or how to use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample project in sdk called `DelayedConfirmation`. If you have samples downloaded in your SDK Manager - you can find if here: `sdk\samples\android-20\wearable\DelayedConfirmation`

Part of `main_activity.xml` file:

```
    <android.support.wearable.view.DelayedConfirmationView
        android:id="@+id/delayed_confirmation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:circle_color="@color/blue"
        app:circle_radius="@dimen/circle_radius"
        app:circle_radius_pressed="@dimen/circle_radius_pressed"
        app:circle_padding="@dimen/circle_padding"
        app:circle_border_width="@dimen/circle_border_normal_width"
        app:circle_border_color="@color/white"/>
```

so the only extra attribute here is:

```
    app:circle_radius_pressed="@dimen/circle_radius_pressed"
```

in MainActivity.java class there are almost the same lines as you set:

```
    delayedConfirmationView = (DelayedConfirmationView) findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation);
    delayedConfirmationView.setTotalTimeMs(NUM_SECONDS * 1000);
    ...
    delayedConfirmationView.setListener(this);
```

But in addition they also invoke `.start()` method:

```
    delayedConfirmationView.start();
```

### EDIT:

I've tested the `DelayedConfirmationView` with just FrameLayout and it works just fine, so BoxInsetLayout has nothing to do here.
Even after copy&paste your `DelayedConfirmationView` xml code everything also works OK, the grayish circle button is displayed on screen. So I was surprised a bit:)
[image]

After playing more with this code I've realized that you have wrong `xmlns:app` line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/android.support.wearable.view"
```

You cannot specify the package of library where the attributes are from (the same way like you cannot use `android.support.wearable.R` class - You need to use R class from your own package. You need to use:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and then everything work fine in your code. This is the reason why after replacing root view with copied `BoxInsetLayout` code (with proper `xmlns`) the button the code has started to work:)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the samples - I didn't see them!  So, to view anything I had to put everything in a BoxInsertLayout (as in sample), then I could see everything. Also yes I needed the start() method to get animation running.

Comment: interresting... why BoxInsetLayout is supposed to make any difference? It only apply some paddings for round screen and on square one the attribute "android:layout_box" is ignored (according to docs). So on square screen it should behave like standard FrameLayout. Once I'll come back home I will play with DelayedConfirmationView a bit:)

Comment: I don't know. But to make anything show with my code, I had to make my view layouts match_parent.  But then the animation circle wouldn't show up, and only showed if I used BoxInsertLayout, and put it back to wrap_content, as in sample.  Very odd I know!

Comment: Please see my updated answer - Another mystery solved:)

Comment: Oh right! Well done for finding that subtly - and thanks for your help!